# Trying to set up mysql-connector-python and getting error

Tags: python-3.x, mysql-python, mysql-connector

I have the package installed and it does not show errors until I run it and i get this..

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/andrewmayes/virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dnspython3-1.12.0-py3.5.egg-info/practice.py", line 2, in <module>
        import mysql.connector
      File "/Users/andrewmayes/virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mysql/connector/__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
        import _version
    ImportError: No module named '_version'
```

And when I try to upgrade...

```
Collecting myswl-connector-python
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement myswl-connector-python (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for myswl-connector-python
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be mysWl-connecot-python?